# Please give me the real world project with Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I new to Spring and Hibernate -- I have seen lot of courses and simple mini-projects, but I feel that it is not enough.

Where can I find some "real" projects where Spring is used.

My aim is to understand typical architecture of Spring application...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page http://www.furkanzumrut.com/open-source-project-using-spring-hibernate-techologies talks about a few open-source projects which use Spring and Hibernate.

For example:

- [Broadleaf Commerce](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce)
- [ZKSample2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zksample2/)
- [Agile Express](https://sourceforge.net/projects/agileexpress/) - a bit older, but **real world** one
- [Life Ray](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal)
- [Zipkin](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin) - see zipkin-server module for example